# react navigation giving error undefined is not an object(evaluating 'this.props.navigation')

Tags: react-native

I am new to react native I am using expo app to run my code I dont have index file as explained in other questions all the files i have are app.js ,login.js, router.js,home.js and My application flow should go like this Login> on button click > Home 
but on button click I am getting error Undefined is not an object(evaluating 'this.props.navigation'),
please help me where i am going wrong. 
thanks in advance.

```js
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import Login from './containers/Login/Login';
import {Navigate} from './containers/Navigation/Router';
import { AppRegistry } from 'react-native';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (<Login navigation={this.props.navigation}/>);
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

```js
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text,TextInput,Button,Image, View } from 'react-native';
import Navigate from '../Navigation/Router';
import RNChart from 'react-native-chart';

export default class Login extends React.Component{
  static navigationOptions = {
    title:'Login',
  };

  render() {
    const navigate  = this.props.navigation;
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
      <RNChart style={styles.chart}
                    chartData={chartData}
                    verticalGridStep={5}
                    type="bar"
                    xLabels={xLabels}>
                </RNChart>
      <Image
          source={require('../../NCS.png')}
        />
        <TextInput
          style={styles.textInput}
          placeholder="Username"
        />
        <TextInput
          style={styles.textInput}
          placeholder="Password"
          secureTextEntry= {true}
        />
        <Button
          onPress={this._handlePress}
          title="Login"
          color="#0086b3"
        />
      </View>
    );
  }

  _handlePress(event) {
      //navigate('Home')
      this.props.navigation.navigate('Home', {name: 'Home'})
  }

}

var chartData = [
    {
        name:'BarChart',
        type:'bar',
        color:'purple',
        widthPercent:0.6,
        data:[
            30, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 21, 13, 21, 34, 55, 30
        ]
    },
    {
        name:'LineChart',
        color:'gray',
        lineWidth:2,
        showDataPoint:false,
        data:[
            10, 12, 14, 25, 31, 52, 41, 31, 52, 66, 22, 11
        ]
    }
];
 
var xLabels = ['0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','11'];

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },

  textInput: {
    padding: 10,
    width: 200,
  },

  chart: {
        position: 'absolute', top: 16, left: 4, bottom: 4,right: 16
  }
});
```

```js
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import {Navigate} from '../Navigation/Router';

export default class Home extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    title:'Home',
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text> Work under progress</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

```js
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import {StackNavigator} from 'react-navigation';
import Login from '../Login/Login';
import Home from '../Home/Home';

export default Navigate = StackNavigator({
  Home: { screen: Home, },
});
```

Comment: You are not binding your function. Which ends up this keyword to be undefined.

Comment: can you be more specific how can i do that?

Comment: Like this: `onPress={this._handlePress.bind(this)}` or define handlePress like this: `handlePress = () => { ... }`

Comment: I tried both of them but getting same error

Comment: Hmm. How is App component connected to navigator?

Comment: I used Login component in  app.js file and imported both router and login component into app.js

Comment: Probably this.props.navigation is not defined at App.js so passing it to Login screen is just passing an undefined value. How does your app component gets navigator from props?

Comment: can you please go through the code files that i attached above and tell me how to use that stack navigator to navigate to home screen on button press

Comment: Uhm Im on mobile right now, but let me try. Include App with screen:App to StackNavigator. Actually, this should be enough. Remember to bind the function as I mentioned above

Comment: I added these two lines to router.js file

Comment: import App from '../../App';

Comment: App: { screen: App, },

Comment: but it gives me new error {Route 'App' should declare a screen}

Comment: Hmm. Cant help further but the problem is your navigation configuration. Follow the basic example at reactnavigation.org

Comment: can you share the whole code repository, so that I can try it at my end?

Comment: I didn't commited this code to repository but you can use the files that are attached above if you willing to give it a try

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that React Navigation is not connected to your App component as @Eden mentioned.  The component you return in App needs to be your StackNavigator.

Here's a very good tutorial that show's this with a TabNavigator.
https://hackernoon.com/getting-started-with-react-navigation-the-navigation-solution-for-react-native-ea3f4bd786a4